# Webscraping with mechanize and beautifulsoup - cannot write output file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, output, mechanize

I need to get lots of data specific to rivercruising, so I am working with alteryx, and for scraping I want to use python from the command line. I need to write the output file to json or to csv. The output file is empty. The hashtags in the code are for processing the output file in alteryx, as the scraped text already contains ",". Preferably I would love to map the output to Json. My code is as follows:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

mech = Browser()

url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/viking-river-cruises/viking-aegir-schedule/'
page = mech.open(url)

html = page.read()
html.replace('charset="ISO-8859-1"','charset=utf-8')
s = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
content = s.findAll('div', id="content")
link = s.findAll("a")
h1 = s.findAll("h1")

table = s.findAll("table", border="1")

for link in s.findAll("a"):
    linktext = link.text
    linkhref = link.get("href")

for h1 in s.findAll("h1"):
    ship = h1.text

h2_1 = s.h2
h2_1.text
h2_2 = h2_1.find_next('h2')
itinerary_1 = h2_2.text
h2_3 = h2_2.find_next('h2')
itinerary_2 = h2_3.text
h2_4 = h2_3.find_next('h2')
itinerary_3 = h2_4.text

for table in content:
    table0 = s.findAll("table", border='0')

    for tr in s.findAll("table", border='1'):
        trs1 = s.findAll("tr")
        table1 = tr.text.replace('\n','|')
        tds1 = s.findAll('td')
        uls1 = s.findAll('ul')
        lis1 = s.findAll('li')



    for tr in s.findAll("table", border='0'):
        trs2 = s.findAll("tr")
        table2 = tr.text.replace('\n','|')
        tds2 = s.findAll('td')
        uls2 = s.findAll('ul')
        lis2 = s.findAll('li')

all_data=ship+"#"+table1+"#"+table2+"#"+itinerary_1+"#"+itinerary_2+"#"+itinerary_3


all_data = open("Z:/txt files/all_data.txt", "w")
print all_data >> "Z:/txt files/all_data.txt"
```

Comment: If you change all `>` to four spaces, that code will get nice StackOverflow formatting.

Comment: For cvs can't you just change this line `all_data=ship+"#"+table1+"#"+table2+"#"+itinerary_1+"#"+itinerary_2+"#"+itinerary_3` to `all_data=ship+","+table1+","+table2+","+itinerary_1+","+itinerary_2+","+itinerary_3+"\n"` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to add some more detail to this post, as it's currently unclear what you've tried, what's not working, what error messages you're seeing, etc. For help on how to properly format your questions on SO, these docs are super helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also the level that your print statement is at will only get the last table since it is at the same level as `for table in content`

Comment: Thank you... I am still struggling to output the file. My output file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get output to your file, try something like instead of the last 2 lines in your code above:

```
with open('all_data_txt, 'w') as f:
    f.write(all_data.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: that gives th error code like follows:                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Scraper tut.py", line 57, in <module>
        f.write(all_data)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in      position 712: ordinal not in range(128)